# Как получить данные из таблицы access db в массив на vb 2005?

Tags: access, vb.net, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Подключаю бд access 2003 к проекту visual basic 2005 (net). Но как извлечь данные из определенного поля в массив не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать recordset и обойти его в цикле.

Comment: Создаю dataset, а как использовать recordset не знаю(

Comment: Тогда здесь почитайте: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315974/ru

Comment: Ладно, спасибо

Comment: В общем всё получилось OleDbConnection использовал